# Formula for calculating the velocity of falling fluid along slope

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a question.

[image]

We are given a slope with data as the above image. And there is a hose on the slope, and the hose has a friction. (Perhaps, there is a possibility of existence of other data about the friction, for example, coefficient of friction and so on).

And fluid is falling through the hose along the slope.

Then, is there any associated formula for calculating the velocity of the fluid at floor ?

Can anyone helps?

Comment: By friction, do you mean viscous fluid friction within the hose?

Comment: Yeh, that conditinon also welcome. In fact, this question is associated with some experiment for creation of some deivce. And I'm not expert in physics and discussing this question with other questioner in my office(Company). For most correct result(formula such as $v=\sqrt{2gh}$ maybe causes 8 times as many errors with the experiement, so more sharp formula is required), we are examining the variables in as many cases as possible. So, if you provide associated formula as many as possible, it will be pleasure. But for the case of viscous fluid friction, it's also Okay and maybe helpful.

Comment: This is more than a person with little physics or engineering experience can confidently handle.  If getting the correct result really matters, you are going to need to rely on someone with significant physics or engineering experience (with specific experience in fluid mechanics).  I suggest hiring a consultant, possibly a professor in the mechanical- or chemical engineering department of your local university.

Comment: O.K. Thanks, perhaps, do you know about any formula when viscous fluid friction is given?